# This Partner doesn't accept incoming connection

Tags: teamviewer

There are two laptops. Both are with Windows 10 Home S Mode. In this Windows Edition, only apps from Microsoft Store can be downloaded.

That's why I downloaded Teamviewer in both computer from Microsoft Store.
While connecting each other using Teamviewer Windows App, I see same error message on both, **This Partner doesn't accept incoming connection**.

Please let me know, what I need check in Partner Computer or how to fix it?

Regards
John

Comment: Does it happen to every device, or are you only trying to connect to one particular session?

Comment: Tryu using the full app downloaded from TeamViewer - as per [Solved: Cant connect two laptops: "This partner does not accept incoming ... - TeamViewer Community - 7316](https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/TeamViewer-General/Cant-connect-two-laptops-quot-This-partner-does-not-accept/td-p/7316)

Comment: Also check [The partner does accept incoming connections - TeamViewer Community - 12167](https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/TeamViewer-General/The-partner-does-accept-incoming-connections/td-p/12167)